# Loading SQLite.Interop.dll file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In `.vbproj` I have:

```
<Content Include="x64\SQLite.Interop.dll"/>
```

This causes that it adds a directory with the file expected as in the screenshot

[image]

But this is only a reference to a file that does not exist

In `package.config` I have:

```
<package id="Sqlite.Interop.Net46.x64" version="1.0.109" targetFramework="net46" />
```

When I try to build or Publish project I have:

```
Could not copy the file "C:\Users\user\Desktop\web_app\MyProj\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll" because it was not found.
```

When I use:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

[image]

File `SQLite.Interop.dll` changed status from `Checked In` to `Ignored` **but everything works fine**

**I would like it to work without additional Update or copying files**

What is wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify: you say everything works fine, but then you ask what is wrong.  Does everything work fine?

Comment: @Amy Everything works fine after executing the command `Update-Package -reinstall`. It can't be like that. The project is reusable and not everyone will know or want to undergo some procedures to make the project work. Everything must be operational without unnecessary actions

Comment: The file does not exist in that directory. When you install the package the files are stored in the packages folder. It can only copy the file if it exists.

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend I know I can copy. But that's not the point. How to make it that you do not have to copy

Comment: I installed this package into a sandbox project, and it created the x64 folder in the project.  The dll was added to that folder.

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue.  Part of the usual workflow when pulling down a project for the first time is to pull down Nuget packages.  You don't generally want to add nuget package files into your source control.  If you want the DLL part of source control, then don't add it as a nuget package.  Just download the file and add it to the project.

Comment: @Amy Then we will have one version rigidly and permanently. The project is OpenSource and depending on when someone is using it can update the data and use the old version here

Comment: Then I don't see the problem.  Add a step to your developers workflow.  (1) pull down the project from source control, (2) pull down missing nuget packages.  You can't have it both ways.